# Lower bound for asymptotic time of sorting algorithms

Tags: reference-request, computational-complexity, sorting

I am dabbling in sorting algorithms in my Algorithms course in university.

Is there any proof for a lower bound on the asymptotic time cost of a sorting algorithm?

Or, to word my question differently, do we know whether it is possible to sort N elements faster than $N\log (N)$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Lower_bound_for_the_average_number_of_comparisons. Turned out that we know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean comparison-based. First, there are $n!$ permutations of the given input. One comparison halves the numbers of permutations so one definitely has to do $log_2(n!)$ comparisons, also know as $n*log_2(n)$.

Now, there are many situations where one could do significantly* better but requires some knowledge of the input data. Some examples are sorting, say, [64-bit integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort), [bounded integers](https://yourbasic.org/algorithms/fastest-sorting-algorithm/) or [partial sorted input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort).

*significantly is a bit relative here: $n*log_2(n)$ is already plenty fast.